# If a div exists override top position css of another div

Tags: javascript, css, conditional-statements, overriding

I am a beginner in Javascript, and I want to figure out how to change the top position of a div class if another div is visible on the web page.
For example, when a user is connected, the adminbar is visible on top of a website, and I want to override the top position of another div class inside the website.

The HTML :

```html
<!-- A if The div is visible -->
<div id="wpadminbar" class="nojq"></div>
```

```html
<!-- B The Other Element will change css top position if the Adminbar A is visible -->
<div onmouseover="mouseOverToggle()" onmouseout="mouseOutToggle()" id="new" class="child new wrapperInscription"></div>
```

What I tried in javascript:

```js
var adminbar = document.getElementById("wpadminbar");
var coquillage = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapperInscription");

if (adminbar.style.position === "fixed") {
  document.getElementsByClassName("wrapperInscription").style.top="86px";
} else {
  document.getElementsByClassName("wrapperInscription").style.top="55px";
}

// if ( $('#wpadminbar').length > 0)
//   $('.wrapperInscription').css('top','86px');
```

It doesn't work for me, how can I manage to make it work please ? Is my syntax correct ?

[The-shell-I-want-to-replace-according-to-the-dark-top-menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RKXn.jpg)

Comment: it does not work that way for multiple reasons. `getElementsByClassName` will return a **HTML Collection Object** which is a list not a single element. As such you always need to iterate through the list. Next ,`adminbar.style.position === "fixed"` expects that the element has an inline-style. It does not check if a CSS style applies.

Comment: For your question, it misses context. What do you mean with visible? Do you hide that menu or do mean with visible it is scrolled into viewport? How do you hide or show that element? why top 86px and 55px? What is the rule to that?

Comment: Thanks a lot @tacoshy. I joined a picture of my issue. As you can see, the "shell" image is not aligned because of the top dark menu of wordpress. That's why I am asking how to change css style of one div according to another div ?